# How to get distinct records in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

```
FUNDFAMILY_ID    FUND_NAME                REPORTSECTION_ID           
--------------------------------------------------------------
172295295    VANGUARD GROWTH FUND (Retail)  126345
172295295    VANGUARD GROWTH FUND (Retail)  126354
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

But i need to get the results like below:

```
FUNDFAMILY_ID     FUND_NAME                   REPORTSECTION_ID
--------------------------------------------------------------
172295295   VANGUARD GROWTH FUND (Retail)   126345
```

Inside a stored procedure i have a query like below which gives duplicate rows

```
    INSERT INTO #TABLE_REPORTSECTIONDATA (FUND_NAME, FUNDFAMILY_ID, REPORTSECTION_ID)

                SELECT DISTINCT @FUNDNAME_TEMP , @FUNDID_TEMP, EntryPointViewsId
                FROM EntryPointViews EPV
                ORDER BY EntryPointViewsId
```

DISTINCT keyword is not giving me the correct results.please suggest

Comment: The behaviour is like expected. You get two rows as the AnotherId is different in those rows. 

Maybe your business case is to get the max or min anotherid? Otherwise it would be the correct behaviour. Can you give detailed information?

Comment: Why do you want the record with `126345` and not the record with `126354`?

Comment: One time one records should insert to DB .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DISTINCT is giving you the correct result, the records are distinct by all columns you have specified. What do you want instead? Just unique according to the ID and the Description? Which `AnotherID` want to take from each group?

If you just want an arbitrary you can use `MIN` or `MAX` with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ID, Description, MIN(AnotherID)
FROM EntryPointViews EPV
GROUP BY ID, Description
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `ROW_NUMBER()` with partitioning, this query should work for you:

```
SELECT FUNDFAMILY_ID, FUND_NAME, REPORTSECTION_ID
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FUNDFAMILY_ID ORDER BY REPORTSECTION_ID) AS RN, FUNDFAMILY_ID, FUND_NAME, REPORTSECTION_ID, EntryPointViewsId
    FROM EntryPointViews EPV
    ) AS T
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY EntryPointViewsId;
```